# Adding elements to list in different places

Tags: c#, list

I want to call a constructor in my class to add objects to a list, however at the moment, the lists keep overwriting itself instead of expanding.

Output is:

```
"Note is: " + element.Note + " = priority" + element.Priority
```

I want to achieve:

```
"Note is: " + element.Note + " = priority" + element.Priority //of FIRST note
```

If i run the code again I want the first note to be saved and the second one displayed as well:

```
"Note is: " + element.Note + " = priority" + element.Priority
"Note is: " + element.Note + " = priority" + element.Priority
```

Main method:

```
private static void utskrift(int choice)
        {
            if (choice== 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nPut in the note: ");
                string notering = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the priority: ");
                int priority= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Note addnote = new Note(note, priority);
                Box putinbox = new Box(addnote);
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to submit a new note?");
                int choice= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                utskrift(choice);
```

Note class:

```
public Note(string note, int priority)
{
    this.note = notering;
    this.priority = prio;                
}
```

Box class:

```
class Box
{
   List<Note> collection = new List<Note>();

    public Box(Note addnote)
    {
        Collection.Add(addnote);
        Console.WriteLine("Note has been added!\n");
        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Note is: " + element.Note + " = priority" + element.Priority);
        }
```

Comment: you need to clean up the code and show if from the entry point and what's initially called.. I would also recommend using the debugger to step thru the code. Pinpoint the issue and or error and tell us what line(s) the problem is happening..  if you are going to show the class show all of the classes not just the Box Class.. `Collection.Add(note);` is that a typo..?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE]. At current moment there is no example that shows adding `Note` to an existing `Box` (which seem to be the part you actually have problem with).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've updated my main method. Please have a lookthrough if you may.

Comment: why are you not posting all parts of the code.. you are leaving out all closing `}` please use the debugger to step through your code have you attempted to do that first..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `collection` is created inside each `Box` object and one note is added to it in the constructor of `Box`.

The collection should either be global or static within the `Box` class. Static means that all box objects are sharing the same collection object. (If this is really what you want)

```
class Box
{
    private static List<Note> collection = new List<Note>();
    //      ^^^^^^
    ...
}
```

---

If, however, you want to be able to add several notes to the same box, you must either be able to pass several notes to the constructor or have an additional method allowing you to add notes after the box has been constructed.

---

Note: The constructor is executed **once** each time you create a **new** object. So you cannot call the constructor repeatedly on the same object. See: [Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)

---

Probably you should refactor your code like this

```
class Box
{
    List<Note> collection = new List<Note>();

    public void AddNote(Note note)
    {
        collection.Add(note);
        Console.WriteLine("Note has been added!\n");
        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Note is: " + element.Note + " = priority" + element.Priority);
        }
    }
}
```

Pass the box as parameter

```
private static void utskrift(Box box, int choice)
{
    if (choice== 1)
    {
        ...
        Note addnote = new Note(note, priority);
        box.AddNote(addnote);
        ...
    ...
}
```

And then call it like this

```
Box box = new Box();
while(true)
{
    int choice = <read the user choice>; // Pseudo code
    if (<the user wants to terminate>)
        break;
    utskrift(box, choice);
}
```

This means that you create the box once with `new` before the entry loop!

---

It would also be better to separate the logic from input and output and from data keeping. Now your box is not only a data structure for notes but it also does some output on the console when notes are added. Is it really the boxes task to write to the console? You could have the box notify you through an event.

```
public class NotifyingBox
{
    private List<Note> notes = new List<Note>();

    public event Action<NotifyingBox> NoteAdded;

    public IEnumerable<Note> Notes => notes;

    public void AddNote(Note note)
    {
        notes.Add(note);
        NoteAdded?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

The `NotifyingBox` class can be used like this:

```
public static void Test()
{
    NotifyingBox box = new NotifyingBox();
    box.NoteAdded += Box_NoteAdded;
    box.AddNote(new Note { Text = "aaa", Priority = 1 });
    box.AddNote(new Note { Text = "bbb", Priority = 2 });
}

private static void Box_NoteAdded(NotifyingBox box)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Note has been added!");
    foreach (Note note in box.Notes) {
        Console.WriteLine($"  Note is: {note.Text} = priority{note.Priority}");
    }
}
```

Now you can do different things when a note has been added to the box without having to change the box. The box is kept clean and does only do box-things.

---

*Note: I am using the new C# 6.0 syntax available in Visual Studio 2015.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
My output now works as expected.

I later on want to save the everything in the list on program execution, and on the next startup I want to be able to edit notes priority, would my current design be suitable for this or should I try a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that each time you use "new Box(addnote);" you're creating a new instance of the "Box" class and therefore a new, empty "collection" list. In order to correct this, create a method in the "Box" class to add to the "collection".

```
public void AddNote(Note addnote)
{
    collection.Add(note);
    Console.WriteLine("Note has been added!\n");
    foreach (var element in collection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Note is: " + element.Note + " = priority" + element.Priority);
    }
}
```

And then when you add a new note, simply use the previous instance of the "Box" class with the new method. For example:

```
Box box = new Box(addnote);//Creates the instance of the "Box" class.
```

//Other stuff inbetween.

```
box.AddNote(addnote);//Add another note to the previous instance of "Box".
```